PubSub-Airflow-MSSQL how to load correctly
Please tell me how to correctly build a data flow from PubSub to MS SQL?
Maybe there is a link to an article on how to do this correctly?
What's on hand:

There is someone else's PubSub, which has the topic I need, for which I created the subscription I need. Volume of 5 million messages per day.
I have my MS SQL in which I want to see all these messages.
There is my Airflow.
And then there is my GCP, GCS, etc.

What I've done:

Created an Airflow dag that uses pubsub_v1
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient.from_service_account_file(key_file)
loading messages from the queue
subscriber.pull
I decrypt and process each one separately, create a dataframe and insert it into SQL via BCP
confirmation of message processing using subscriber.acknowledge(ack_ids_list)
repeat the process

it works, but is it correct?
Questions:

Maybe there is a link to an article on how to do this correctly?
Is it normal to do this? Shouldn't it be loaded into GCS first?
Is it normal to use pubsub_v1?
Is it okay to confirm them through ack_ids_list? Perhaps it is possible to be reliable as a general scope?

Help. I'm burning. Lots of information and little time. I continue to read the documentation. :)

There are many articles that could help you, you just need to know how to "ask google". I'd say it is a good practice leverage GCS this way, as it decouples the data processing steps and provides sustainability. There is nothing wrong with using pubsub_v1. Acknowledging messages through ack_ids_list is the correct way to confirm their processing. However, you need to ensure that your processing and acknowledgement logic is robust enough to handle failures gracefully.

Airflow is not the place to do data pipelines, so please avoid it. Only use airflow for orchestrating jobs. You can check Dataflow and write a pipeline that would stream data from pub/sub to your mssql.
